# Testing input value in click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

i have one textfield whose id is date. i want to give an dialog boxmsg when textfield is empty. i am tried the following code a lot times but it never going to execute button click function. Why this happen please tell me

```
var val = $('#date').val();

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {

        if (val != null) {

            $("#dialog").dialog();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `var val = $('#date').val();` inside `click` handler so that `val` will always contain the latest value in the `#date` input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        var val = $('#date').val().trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces
        // Moved inside click handler

        if (!val) { // Check if falsy value

            $("#dialog").dialog();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `val` variable scope is different. So you can try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        if ($('#date').val()){
            $("#dialog").dialog();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Gets the value when you click and alerts if it's empty?

You need to get the textbox's value when you click, otherwise it will be empty since it's going to be set ONCE, when the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
      var textbox = $('#textbox').val();
      if (textbox.length == 0){
        alert();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Type here"><br>
<button id="btnSubmit">Click me</button>
```